# Object Oriented Programming in socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, ecmascript-6

i was doing socket.io based programmings since so long.

now as time spent doing more complex systems and apps based on socket.io, using all js in ES6, classes etc. and all the time lots of emit and on are more hard to maintain.

so i was wondering if there is any way we can use socket.io also in oops way.
for example there is lib called dnode which more look like this, but underlaying note using socket.io i think.

for example see this sample code.

```
/**
 Server.js
 */
client.on('login',function(user,pass,cb){
    var user=User.authenticate(user,pass);
    if(user instanceof User){
         cb(null, user);
    } else {
        cb(user);// error
    }
});



/**
 Client.js
 */

server.emit('login','test','test',function(err,user){
    if(err)
        return console.error(err);
    var picture=user.getPhoto(); // this method is defined on server...
    user.on('new_post',function(post){
        // events on object...

    });
    // all data ob user class are synced via server automatically..

});
```

overall instead of joining room and leaving room, we can just pass objects here and there, and Base class can do all the underlying things automatically. which lead to more cleaner and robots code flow.

i am looking for reinventing wheel so need your suggestion about any exiting libraries or what more to come in future for socket.io

Comment: socket.io is already OOP

Comment: right now i just created a little lib for this thing.. i mean to say that to controll objects remote and local via socket io, no more lots of emits and ons and single file..

Comment: i'll share the code soon.